# Shell script to sparsely checkout SVN files changed in particular revision is not working

Tags: shell, svn, version-control

I have the following script which is meant to sparsely checkout the files for a certain revision in SVN. I wanted to copy these files over as a "patch" of sorts.

The repo folder was checked out as `--depth empty`, so before running this script the root of the repo should just have `.svn`. I did this as the repo is huge and I just wanted to quickly create a patch from a certain revision.

```
for currentFile in $(svn log -r 3131 -v | grep "/branches" | cut -c 7-)
do
    curDir="$(dirname $currentFile)"

    curName=$(basename "$currentFile")

    svn checkout svn://localhost/LocalRepo@3131 $curDir --depth empty

    cd $curDir

    svn up -r 3131 $curName

    cd /e/partials/RepoInstance
done
```

The for loop gets the content that I would like.

`curDir` and `curName` seem to extract the right strings.

The `checkout` of the directory creates the folder, but the `up` doesn't create a file, but doesn't error either.

The `up` says `Updating myFile.blah to revision 3131` and then `At revision 3131` as if it's worked.

I initially had this a lot simpler without the folder checkout, `cd` in and out, but I ran into problems such as `svn: E155007: None of the targets are working copies`.